# NotORM: How to fetch data?

Tags: php, notorm

I´m having trouble using selects, I tried reading the documentation but it's not too clear, and the forums that talk about it are few and inactive.

I want to do a simple select, so I tried:

```
$applications = $NOTORM->user_types()
                        ->select('id, group_title')
                        ->where('id', 1);
return $applications;
```

That however gives me back a NotORM object where I don't see the resulting rows that I get when I do a normal: `SELECT id, group_title FROM user_types WHERE id = 1`

I tried using the fetch() but not really sure how to use it. Any insights?

Comment: Can you please add `die(var_dump($applications));` just before your `return` line, and add the output to your question?

Comment: make sure user_types is the exact name of the table.  also, have you tried printing out $applications['id'] to see if you are getting any data?  Another thing you can check is if you initialized the $NOTORM obj correctly by passing in a PDO obj.

Answer (score 7):

Actually, recommended by the author of NotORM is to use:

```
<?php
array_map('iterator_to_array', iterator_to_array($result));
?>
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem till I realized that you have to loop over result.
Try

```
foreach($applications as $application) {
     echo $application["id"] . ": " . $application["group_title"]
}
```

Alternatively as you mentioned you can use `fetch()` which will fetch you one row at a time.

```
$row=$applications->fetch();
echo $row["id"];
```

**EDIT:**

To get all the row data as plain associative array instead of NotORM Object I have come across 2 techniques:

1. `foreach($row as $key => $value) {
     $data[$key]=$value;
   }`
2. `$data=iterator_to_array($row);` - I haven't fount a NotOrm function that does this but I found that Notorm uses this technique internally(somewhere).

Answer (score 0):

To actually get **only** the **data** array of the row, you have to access NotORM_Row->row param, but it is '*protected*' by default. So to use it like this:

```
$row = $NOTORM->user_types()
              ->select('id, group_title')
              ->where('id', 1)
              ->fetch()->row;                //here is the magic :)
```

You first need to 'hack' core NotORM_Row class in 'NotORM/Row.php',

by replacing

`protected $row, $result;`

to

`public $row, $result;`

**Note:** You have to call fetch() on NotORM results, because it will return the NotORM_Row object where the row data is placed.

Comment: this is NOT a solution

Answer (score 0):

Just add this code somewhere inside the NotORM_Result class:

```
function result() { return (Object)$this->result_array(); }
function result_array() {
    foreach($this as $row) {    $ret[] = iterator_to_array($row);   }
    return $ret;
}
```

And use it like:

```
    $applications = $NOTORM->user_types()
                            ->select('id, group_title')
                            ->where('id', 1);
    return $applications->result(); //To return it as an Plain Object
//or
   return $applications->result_array();  //To return it as a Assoc Array
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to define this PHP function:

```
function getArray($obj){
  $arr = array();

  foreach ($obj as $objSingle) {

      $arrRow = array();
      foreach ($objSingle as $key => $value) {
          $arrRow[$key] = $value;
      }
      $arr[] = $arrRow;
  }
  return $arr;
```

}

And use it by calling:

```
$arr = getArray($applications);
```

Answer (score 0):

NotOrm added a function that return raw row data than names `jsonSerialize`. You can get row data array by this function.

Example:

```
$row=$db->MyTable->where('X','93054660084')->fetch();

var_dump($row->jsonSerialize());
```

Output:

```
array (size=5)
  'X' => string '93054660084' (length=9)
  'Idc' => string '1132' (length=4)
  'IdH' => string '1' (length=1)
  'Mab' => string '0' (length=1)
  'Tar' => string 'xsderf' (length=10)
```

For multi record data you need to use foreach and apply it to all records.

Answer (score 0):

> It can be done like this.

```
 function comboBuilder2($tbl, $name, $lable, $value, $value2, $value3, $selected = NULL, $cond, $sort = NULL){
global $db;
$html = '';
$sort1 = (!empty($sort)) ? "order by sort asc" : '';
$sql = "select * from " . $tbl . " " . $cond . " " . $sort1 . "";
//echo $sql;
$sth = $db->query($sql);
$rs = $sth->fetchAll();
//print_r($rs);
if ($rs[0] > 0) {
    foreach ($rs as $row) {
        if ($selected == $row[$value])
            $sel = 'selected = "selected" ';
        else
            $sel = '';
        echo $row[$lable];
        //$html .= '<option value="' . $row[$value] . '"  data-min="' . $row[$value2] . '"  data-max="' . $row[$value3] . '" ' . $sel . '>' . $row[$lable] . '</option>';
    }
    $html .= '';
}
return $html;
```

}